# How to Deploy a Custom Docker Image using Bitnami Postgresql Helm Chart

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I'm attempting to use a Bitnami Helm chart for Postgresql to spin up a custom Docker image that I create (I take the Bitnami Postgres Docker image and pre-populate it with my data, and then build/tag it and push it to my own Docker registry).

When I attempt to start up the chart with my own image coordinates, the service spins up, but no pods are present.  I'm trying to figure out why.

I've tried running `helm install` with the `--debug` option and I notice that if I run my configuration below, only 4 resources get created (`client.go:128: [debug] creating 4 resource(s)`), vs 5 resources if I try to spin up the default Docker image specified in the Postgres Helm chart.  Presumably the missing resource is my pod.  But I'm not sure why or how to fix this.

My `Chart.yaml`:

```
apiVersion: v2
name: test-db
description: A Helm chart for Kubernetes
type: application
version: "1.0-SNAPSHOT"
appVersion: "1.0-SNAPSHOT"
dependencies:
  - name: postgresql
    version: 11.9.13
    repository: https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami
    condition: postgresql.enabled
```

My `values.yaml`:

```
postgresql:
  enabled: true
  image:
    registry: myregistry.com
    repository: test-db
    tag: "1.0-SNAPSHOT"
    pullPolicy: always
    pullSecrets:
      - my-reg-secret
  service:
    type: ClusterIP
  nameOverride: test-db
```

I'm starting this all up by running

```
helm dep up
helm install mydb .
```

When I start up a Helm chart (`helm install mychart .`), is there a way to see what Helm/Kubectl is doing, beyond just passing the `--debug` flag?  I'm trying to figure out why it's not spinning up the pod.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was on this line in my `values.yaml`:

```
    pullPolicy: always
```

The pullPolicy is case sensitive.  Changing the value to `Always` (note capital A) fixed the issue.

I'll add that this error wasn't immediately obvious, and there was no indication in the output from running the Helm command that this was the issue.

I was able to discover the problem by looking at how the `statefulset` got deployed (I use `k9s` to navigate Kubernetes resources): it showed `0/0` for the number of pods that were deployed.  Describing this `statefulset`, I was able to see the error in capitalization in the startup logs.